# Why JavaScript code disabled my submit button

Tags: javascript, laravel, button, submit

I used JavaScript in a Laravel view that disabled my submit button. I have no idea the problem is, but when I comment out my JavaScript code, my submit button works properly. The code is a countdown timer that, after 30 seconds, adds a button to my Blade view.

**Form**

```
<form action="{{ route('do.verify.phone') }}" method="post" class="pt-2">
    @csrf
    @if($m = Session('verify_unsuccessful'))
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                <li>{{$m}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @if (Session('verify_code'))
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            <div id="timer"></div>
            <p>در صورت نیامد کد پس از 30 ثانیه مجددا امتحان کنید</p>
            <form action="{{ route('send.code') }}" method="post">
                <div id="txt"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    @if (Session('send_code'))
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <div class="alert alert-primary">
            <div id="timer"></div>
            <p>در صورت نیامد کد پس از 30 ثانیه مجددا امتحان کنید</p>
            <form action="{{ route('send.code') }}" method="post">
                <div id="txt"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label for="emailaddress">کد احراز هویت </label>
        <input name="code" type="text" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="کد ارسال شده به تلفن همراه خود را وارد کنید"
               autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-0 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit"> ورود</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <script>
      var seconds=30;
      var timer;
      function myFunction() {
          if(seconds < 60) {
              document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
          }
          if (seconds >0 ) {
              seconds--;
          } else {
              clearInterval(timer);
              document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" >ارسال مجدد کد</button>';
          }
      }
      window.onload = function() {
          if(!timer) {
              timer = window.setInterval(function() {
                  myFunction();
              }, 1000);
          }
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Your issue is not clear. What is expected and what is happening ?

Comment: my button with submit type  doesn't work  and my form doesn't submit   but when i comment out my javascript code in related view ,  button works what's wrong with my code? @N69S